# Extract informations from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I would like to extract only some information inside it.

For example I have this:

```
'Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.'
```

And I would like to split it in order to get a list like this:

```
['3 Oscars', '80 wins', '121 nominations']
```

How to do I do in Python?

Thanks

Comment: You should define what are your constraints for extracting information. Numbers followed by words? Every second and third element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *number* followed by *space*, a *word* and then a *word boundary*. This should do:

```
import re

s = 'Won 3 Oscars. Another 80 wins & 121 nominations.'
p = re.compile(r'\d+\s\w+\b')

print(p.findall(s))
# ['3 Oscars', '80 wins', '121 nominations']
```